# Add marker to google maps by using GeoJson

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin, geojson

I have no idea how to add a marker from a **GeoJson**.

The data I have to use is something like:

```
"geometry": {  
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[  
           727053.159,
           4374119.505
        ]
     }
```

I supposed the **coordinates** would be **Latitude** and **Longitude** but what I have tried doesn't work:

```
private fun createMarker(
    latitude: Double,
    longitude: Double,
    title: String,
    snippet: String
): Marker {
    return mMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions()
            .position(LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title(title)
            .snippet(snippet)
    )
}
```

Any idea how to add the marker from geojson data?

Comment: Your coordinates aren't latitude longitude: these are measured in degrees. Your coordinates are projected using an unknown projection (based on the available data) with units in another coordinate space - placing them may be difficult. Where abouts is the example point in the question supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

[Andrew Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106086/andrew-reid) is absolutely right: your `GeoJSON` data is not in `WGS84` Latitude/Longitude degrees. You should determine coordinate reference system (CRS) of your `GeoJSON` e.g. by checking its [`"crs"`](https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#coordinate-reference-system-objects) tag. If there is `"crs"` [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown) is some tips how to determine unknown coordinate system. I would start trying from [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system).